# Variable assignments inside for and then if loops

Tags: python

For the following working code, I resorted to creating a class instance to store the name variable of my file output [a_string] and the file object itself [f_object]. I found that variables assigned inside the first if statement did not appear in the scope inside the following elif statement.

```
#Text file splitter, data bewteen the '*' lines are copied into new files.

class Output_file():
    def __init__(self,a_string='none',f_object='none'):
        self.name=a_string
        self.foutput=f_object

outputfile=Output_file()

n=0
filehandle=open('original file.txt')
for line in filehandle:

    if line[0]=='*': #find the '*' that splits the rows of data
        n+=1
        outputfile.name = 'original file_'+str(n)+'.txt'
        outputfile.foutput= open(outputfile.name,'w')
        outputfile.foutput.write(line)

    elif len(line.split()) ==5 and n > 0: #make sure the bulk data occurs in blocks of 5
        outputfile.foutput= open(outputfile.name,'a+')
        outputfile.foutput.write(line)


outputfile.foutput.close()
```

Do I have to use a class instance to store the file name and object or is there a better way?

Comment: how do you know they don't carry to next elif statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables defined in either `if` or `elif` statement should appear in the other. For example:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...  if i%2==0:
...   x = i
...   print(x)
...  else:
...   print(x)
... 
0
0
2
2
4
```

This would not be the case in block-scoped languages, but unfortunately python is not block-scoped, and thus this should work.

Do note however that for this to work, your `name=` must execute before you attempt to use it. That is, your `if` statement MUST execute at least once before your `elif` statement.

Your code lacks comments, but I assume your data looks somewhat like:

```
 This is a header
 blah blah blah
 **************
 16 624 24 57 32
 352 73 47 76 3
 25 6 78 80 21 331
 **************
 234 234 4 64 7
 **************
 **************
 86 57 2 5 14
 4 8 3 634 7
```

And you want to split them into separate files, but only if it's "valid" data. I'd code it like so if I wanted to imitate your style:

```
def isSeparatorLine(line):
    return line[0] = '*'
def isValidLine(line):
    return len(line.split())==5

groupNum = 0
outputFile = None
with open('original file.txt') as original:
    for line in original:
        if isSeparatorLine(line):
            groupNum += 1
            outputFilename = 'original file_{}.txt'.format(groupNum)
            if outputFile:
                outputFile.close()
            outputFile = open(outputFilename, 'w')
            outputFile.write('New file with group {}'.format(groupNum))
        elif group>0 and isValidLine(line):
            outputFile.write(line)
```

I'd however personally prefer to write it like so:

```
from itertools import *

FILENAME = 'original file.txt'
FILENAME_TEMPLATE = 'stanza-{}.txt'

def isSeparatorLine(line):
    return all(c=='*' for c in line)
def isValidLine(line):
    return len(line.split())==5
def extractStanzas(text):
    """
        Yields: [stanza0:line0,line1,...], [stanza1:lineN,lineN+1,...], [stanza2:...]
        where each stanza is separated by a separator line, as defined above
    """
    for isSeparator,stanza in groupby(text.splitlines(), isSeparatorLine):
        if not isSeparator:
            yield stanza

with open(FILENAME) as f:
    stanzas = list(extractStanzas(f.read()))

for i,stanza in enumerate(stanzas[1:]):
    assert all(isValidLine(line) for line in stanza), 'invalid line somewhere: {}'.format(stanza)
    with open(FILENAME_TEMPLATE.format(i), 'w') as output:
        output.write('\n'.join(stanza))
```

Comment: "Each iteration of the for loop resets all variables assigned inside." This is not true. Unless you explicitly re-initialize the variable it will retain it's value until it goes out of scope (i.e. the procedure or module ends). If this were not true you couldn't do things like iterate a value within a loop.

Comment: Thanks Allan, I was not thinking clearly and forgot python was not block-scoped. My bad. Thanks again.

Comment: Most generous reply. Are you missing a def statement for the extractGroups() function? I cannot find any documentation for it.